# How to find newest support libary version for target SDK?

Tags: android, maven, android-support-library

I am compiling for SDK version 26. How can I find out what are the newest support libary versions for the target version?

Comment: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html, browse to find your artifact, and find the highest version number that starts with your `compileSdkVersion`. In your case, it's `26.1.0`.

Comment: 26.1 can't be resolved but 26.+ works. What could cause the problem?

Comment: There is no `26.1`. There is `26.1.0`. Google uses three-level semantic versioning for most libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official doc you can find [all the releases.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

Otherwise you can browse the [new google maven repo](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use + to use latest version like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

It will use the highest version that starts with 26.